# vuejs 2 img src protected by jwt

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

is there any way to get images which are protected by jwt?

laravel route:

```
$api->get('images/{slug}', ['uses'       => 'App\Api\V1\Controllers\ImagesController@show']);
```

laravel show method:

```
public function show($imgid)
{
    if(Auth::check())
    {
        $path = Config::get('fms.images.thumbnail') . '/' . $image->thumbnail;
        return \Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::make($path)->response();
    } else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

vue img:

```
  <img :src="imgurl(photo.id)">
```

vue imgurl method

```
imgurl(imgid) {
   return "/api/images/" + imgid
}
```

returns 400 as i'm not authenticated

thanks

Comment: What guard are you using for authentication on your Api? is it a session guard or the API Token guard? if it's the latter you'll have issues as `Auth::check()` defaults to the web guard not the api guard. you'll have to use `Auth::guard('api')->check()` and need to pass in the api token.

Comment: this is not the problem. the problem is that i've no idea how to handle / display the downloaded image from laravel in vue

Comment: Ok, I'm not entirely understanding your issue. Your `<img :src="imgurl(photo.id)">` is correct in that you will assign the function return value to the source directive on the img. if that's returning a 400 I still think the issue would be due to your Authentication method thinking you're not logged in. That would be a guard issue on Laravel's side. if you remove the `if(Auth::check())` requirement does it still return a 400?

Answer (score 1):

There is a library for Vue.js that allows to pass an auth header:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-auth-image